# Strange SVN scenario - checkouts need to update with no SSH access

Tags: svn

Hoping someone has ran into this scenario and can lead me in the right direction.

- Company A hosts a checkout of www.foo.com on their servers.
- Foo inc. owns the code and would like to host the SVN repo on their servers.
- Company A does not want Foo inc. to have SSH privileges on their servers for promotion.

How does Foo inc. host the code and perform updates to Company A's servers?

I was thinking perhaps a cron job which runs on Company's A servers and looks for updates on Foo's servers?  Should I be looking into CruiseControl or Hudson?  Is there something I'm missing that could be easier?

Thanks.

Comment: you do know you can a user only allow svn on a SSH connection?
command="svnserve -t",no-port-forwarding TYPE KEY COMMENT

You may also wish to specify the options "no-pty",
"no-agent-forwarding", and "no-X11-forwarding", just to give the
client less wiggle room.
Quote from: http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/notes/ssh-tricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your suggestion is perfectly reasonable.

Foo inc hosts the code, and Company A has access to do updates.

You could consider using a distributed VCS such as Mercurial/Bazaar/Git.

More importantly, does Company A REALLY want to automatically update? Obviously I don't know the real-world implementation here, but in general, automatically updating someone elses checkout is... well.. rude (and probably dangerous).

Comment: Automatically update might be a bad phrase.  What I really would like is for Foo inc to push their code live once a commit has occurred without having SSH access.